# How to remove blank icon from launchpad after uninstall app?

Tags: macos, launchpad

I have uninstalled an app from Finder->Applications. But in launchpad, icon of the app still exists. How to remove it?

I've tried to restart Mac, no luck.

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to force launchpad to rebuild it's databases. In the Terminal run

```
rm ~/Library/Application\ Support/Dock/*.db; defaults write com.apple.dock ResetLaunchPad -bool true; killall Dock;
```

NOTE: this method will re-arrange all of your launchpad icons. – Martin Zhai

Comment: The icon still exists after I run this command. :-(

Comment: Try also running `defaults write com.apple.dock ResetLaunchPad -bool true; killall Dock;`

Comment: This time the blank icon disappeared. But be careful, **this method will re-arrange all of your launchpad icons**.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @Martin Zhai, sorry if that was a pain to rebuild.

Answer (score 1):

Much easier solution:
you have to "long-click", just click and keep it pressed in launchpad.
The buttons start to wiggle, the interface is copied from iOS.

Comment: This works most time, but not for this issue. There is no `x` on the icon after long pressing.

Answer (score 1):

Reinstall it and delete it again.

Comment: Sometimes this helps. In a lot of cases, the Mac app store won't let you reinstall something that it thinks is installed. Would you elaborate on what "reinstall it" looks like in specific or in general?